# What is a sufficient condition for the singular values of a square matrix to be the modulus of its eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

My lecturer said " when the matrix M is square and it has complex-conjugate eigenvalues(I mean conjugate pairs of eigenvalues for any non-real eigenvalue), the singular values of M are the modulus of the eigenvalues"

Since it was an incomplete phrase I don't know it he meant " the modulus of the eigenvalues **of $M$**" or " the modulus of the eigenvalues **of $MM'$**. I think he meant the former, but anyway I think is wrong as a general statement. I verified this with a couple of examples in matlab, and found it to be true  for M=[1 -1; 1  1] , but wrong for M=[ 4/5 -3/5 0; 3/5 4/5 0 ; 1 2 2]  So was the lecturer wrong?, What is a sufficient condition for the singular values of a square matrix to be the modulus of its eigenvalues ?
I know the singular values of M are the square root of the eigenvalues of $MM'$ and that M and M' have the same eigenvalues

Comment: It’s the modul*us*

Comment: @FShrike Thanks, I fixed that

Comment: I know what a complex eigenvalue is, but what on earth is a "complex-conjugate eigenvalue"?

Comment: @user1551 Not "a complex conjugate eigenvalue ", but "complex conjugate eigenvalues " or "a pair of complex conjugate eigenvalues ", like a+bi and a-bi

Comment: What you mean is commonly referred to as "conjugate pairs of eigenvalues". Anyway, the statement in question is wrong. Perhaps your lecturer has some special context in mind, such as normal matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Let $USV^\ast$ and $QRQ^\ast$ be a SVD and a Schur upper triangularisation of $A$ respectively. Then $\|S\|_F^2=\|R\|_F^2$. Since the eigenvalues of $A$ are the diagonal entries of $R$, if the singular values and eigenvalues of $A$ can be ordered in a manner such that for each $i$ the $i$-th singular value has the same modulus as the $i$-th eigenvalue, all off-diagonal entries of $R$ must be zero, meaning that $A$ is a normal matrix. The converse is obviously also true.

Comment: I am not following you, what is the sufficient condition and what does normal matrices has to do with this?. First of all, you agree the stament of lecturer was wrong, right?